# Oralce SQL nested or inner join when you need to compare the same table but different rows with unique ID values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a trouble writing a query in ORACLE. I have a Table that contains values. for example:

```
ID  quantity partID 
123   50       10
100   20       10
100   30       11
123   null     8
456   null     100
789   25       123
456   50       9
```

I want to get all rows that has same ID but quantities to be 50 and null (exact same pairs of 50 and null only). for the given example I would like to get:

```
ID  quantity partID 
123   50       10
123   null     8
456   50       9
456   null     100
```

I tried inner join but it doesn't provide the exact output as expected.

Comment: Provide the query that you tried with the join for us to look at

Answer (score 1):

You may try :

```
select ID, quantity, partID
  from tab
 where ID in
(
 select ID
  from tab
 where nvl(quantity,50)=50
 group by ID
 having count(distinct nvl(quantity,0) )>1
);

ID  QUANTITY    PARTID
123    50         10
123   (null)       8
456   (null)     100
456    50          9
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49545/1)

P.S. you may get the same results by commenting out `having count(ID)=2` also but for those cases there may not exist one of `50` or `null` for values of quantity.

Comment: Thank you Barbaros! This doesn't return the values as expected. I'm trying to get rows which is 50 and also has a null value. When i do this in my data it returns every value that's null and not the ones that has 50 and also null.

Comment: @zack welcome friend. Perhaps, you may expand the data set to see what you want to see and don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.quantity = 50 and
       exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.partid = t.partid and t2.value is null)
      ) or
      (t.quantity is null and
       exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.partid = t.partid and t2.value = 50)
      ) ;
```